# jOOQ - returning() without where() not available

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I noticed that the returning() operation is not available without a where(). Is this intentional?

This works:

```
context.deleteFrom(...).where(...).returning().fetch()
```

This doesn't work:

```
context.deleteFrom(...).returning().fetch()
```

Should I consider this 'hack'?

```
context.deleteFrom(...).where(DSL.true()).returning().fetch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't intentional but a bug:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4428

As a workaround, you should use:

```
context.deleteFrom(...).where(DSL.trueCondition()).returning().fetch()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!